# Best way to discern between two items on Bubble.io

Tags: bubble.io

So on my bubble site I am trying to find the best way for the Bubble.io to know when an item is a product or a service. If it is a service, I would need Bubble.io to present either a button or a whole new page for it. Please let me know the best way to do this or if you have a link/article please share it!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way should be to set up a `product_type` field in the database and create conditional displays for your front-end elements.

In detail, you should create the front-end for both product and service types. You hide the front-end elements for products when it's a service and vice versa.